# $(G, \cdot)$ - group such that $|G|<\infty$. $G$ has exactly $2$ subgroups

Tags: group-theory

$(G, \cdot)$ - group such that $|G|<\infty$. $G$ has exactly $2$ subgroups. Prove that order of $a\in G$ is a prime if $a\neq e$ where $e$ is neutral element.

I am stuck. Here is what I got so far:

$G$ has exactly two subgroups that means that the only subgroups are $e$ and $G$.

Let $a^k=e$ and assume that $k$ is not prime, that means $k=p_1 p_2$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are prime numbers. Then $a^k=a^{p_1 p_2}=(a^{p_1})^{p_2}=e^{p_2}$.

Now I am stuck because I think that means that it implies that $a^{p_1}=e$ and then I would know what to do, but does it?

Comment: Hint: If $k$ is not prime, then either $a^{p_1} = e$ in which case $a$ generates a third subgroup, of order $p_1$, or else $(a^{p_1})^{p_2} = e$, in which case $a^{p_1}$ generates a third subgroup.

Answer (score 7):

You have some work to do here. First off, what is your overall proof technique? What you need to prove, given the assumptions, that if $a\in G$ and $a\neq e$, then the order of $a$ is prime.

You (nearly) correctly observe that under the assumptions, the two subgroups of $G$ are $\{e\}$ (to be careful with the notation, this is not the same thing as $e$) and $G$. (You might note that for these to be different, $\vert G\vert$ must be greater than $1$.)

Now how are you going about proving the if-then result you need to prove? You could attempt a direct proof (assume that $a\in G$ and $a\neq e$ and conclude that the order of $a$ is prime), or a proof by contrapositive or contradiction (assume that $a\in G$ and the order of $a$ is not prime, and conclude that $a=e$ or that $G$ is not finite, or that $G$ has more than two subgroups.)

You begin by assuming that $a^k=e$ where $k$ is not prime, so it looks like you are attempting a proof by contrapositive or contradiction, but this isn’t quite the right assumption, because you should assume that the *order* of $a$ is not prime, and that’s not the same thing as assuming $a$ raised to a non-prime power is $e$. Do you know the definition of *order* of an element of a group?

In fact, there are always non-prime values of $k$ for which $a^k=e$. For example, $a^{250\vert G\vert}=e$ for every element $a$ of $G$, so you won’t be able to conclude much about $a$ from that.

You also say that if $k$ is not prime, it is the product of two primes, but this is not true. For example, $12$ is not prime, but it isn’t the product of two primes.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining to the OP what the issues are.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a$ has order $mn$. Consider $\langle a^n\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a \in G$. Then $\langle a \rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$. Given the only subgroups of $G$ are the identity and $G$ itself, either $\langle a \rangle = e$ or $\langle a \rangle = G$. In the first case $a=e$. So suppose not. 
Then $G=\langle a \rangle = \{a,a^2, \cdots , a^n=e$. Hence $G$ is cyclic. Aim is to show $n=p$ for some prime $p$. If not, there exists some integer $m$ such that $\langle a^m \rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $\frac{|G|}{m}$. This leads to our contradiction.